# Collecting handles with Windbg

Tags: windbg, handle

I'm using Windbg sdk to write my own debugger. The debugger is capable of collecting all handles allocated by debugged apps to avoid handle leaks. Here is my code:

```
void zAdvancedDebugger::debugProc(){
    // Creating interfaces including m_dbgClient, m_dbgControl
    if(!createInterfaces()){
        printf("Failed to create debugging interfaces\r\n");
        return;
    }
    std::string strRealCmdLine="\"" + app + "\"  " + args;
    // Every thing's set up so start the app.
    if (( m_dbgClient->CreateProcess(0, (PSTR)strRealCmdLine.c_str(), DEBUG_PROCESS )) != S_OK)
        return ;
    // event loop
    while(true){
        if(m_dbgControl->WaitForEvent(DEBUG_WAIT_DEFAULT,INFINITE)!= S_OK)
            break;
    }
    HRESULT ret=m_dbgControl->Execute(
        DEBUG_OUTCTL_IGNORE,
        ".closehandle -a", // Close all handles allocated
        DEBUG_EXECUTE_NOT_LOGGED );
}
```

The problem is: I can't execute the command ".closehandle -a". Whenever I run the code, I always get "ret   0x80040205 An unexpected exception was raised". Would you please tell me what wrong is with this?

Comment: Did your process start running or was it sitting at the intial breakpoint? It could be that you first need to break into the process before you can execute this command.

Comment: I did write something similar in managed code where I do start a proces with a Windbg server via named pipes and whenever I want to execute a command I do start cdbg.exe which does connect to the server and executes a script. Then I can collect the output from cdb and parse it. Nice and easy. I can even debug myself with this approach if the output of the cdb.exe is redirected to a file which I can parse after the debugger command has finished and let me execute again.

Comment: @AloisKraus Sorry, I don't understand. The command is executed when the loop finishes.

Comment: Hm from the code it looks like you should execute your commands whenver a debugger event was received not when the event loop was left with an error perhaps because the debugee did already terminate?

Comment: @AloisKraus I think the command is problematic. When I modify it to ".handle", everything's OK. :(

Comment: .closehandle -a will close all handles in your target process including shared memory and the debugger thread handle which is needed to communicate with the target process. I am not sure for what this command should be good for because you did nearly kill the process.

Comment: As I read from the documentation of Windbg, ".closehandle -a" - Causes all handles owned by the target application to be closed. Is there any way to close all allocated handles when the debuggee is terminated?

Comment: Yes. The Kernel does free all resources allocated by a process when it is terminated. The only exception are handles which are opened by more than one process e.g. memory mapped files and Desktop Heap objects which tend to pile up if not managed properly.

Comment: @AloisKraus: Have you got any solution for the case in which handles are not managed properly?

Comment: If the kernel cannot clean it up the chances are dim that you can fix it with a debugger. You may be able to find out which handles are the ones which need to be closed but you must fix the application which has the problem.

Comment: @AloisKraus: Actually, I have a my own event call back class which implements LoadModule(), CreateThread(), CreateProcess(). Allocated handles are passed through that functions. So I just store all of them in a list. And when the debuggee's terminated, I use a loop to close all handles (using _try _except to avoid invalid handles). It works well but sometimes the debugger crashes due to an exception of invalid handles. :(

Comment: I had this as well. You create handles with various OS methods and you MUST use the right Close method for it. Not every handle is closed via CloseHandle. If you use the wrong close method it can happen that you close nothing (leak) or that you close something entirely different.

Comment: @AloisKraus: Please have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx. It states that: I can use CloseHandle() to close handles of files, threads and processes. :( So?

Comment: If you have the correct handle close method then you stil have a race condition. You do not seem to know if somebody else did already close the handle. Handles are not random numbers and they are reused once they are closed. When you close at the end every handle you did create (and perhaps closed already some of them) you can close a handle to something you did not create and unleash hell to the application which gets some random errors.

Comment: @AloisKraus: I've got another solution for how to clean up such handles in my debugger. :) I read the process's memory to determine which handles must be closed and it works. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Thats good to hear. By the way what does your debugger do? Something useful you would like share (at least the idea)?

Comment: @AloisKraus: For fuzzing purposes only, the debugger is used to monitor programs such as Chrome, IE, ... :) Are you interested in fuzzing?

Comment: It is interesting but currently I have enough errors to cope with without fuzzing ;-)